# Avoiding usage of fail in parsers from Parsers library

Tags: parsing, haskell, parser-combinators

From what I was told using [fail](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fail) is not recommended and it will later be removed.

What should be properly used instead of fail in the following [Parsers/Trifecta](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsers) example?

```
parserNaturalNoLeadZero :: Parser Integer
parserNaturalNoLeadZero = do
  digits <- some digit
  if length digits > 1 && head digits == '0'
    then fail "Leading Zeros"
    else return $ read digits
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the documentation tells you, a new [`MonadFail`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-Fail.html) class is being introduced to fulfill that role.

But, for stuff like parsers, the sensible choice is usually [`empty`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:empty), which has been around for much longer.

Comment: From the discussion on IRC, what do you think of using unexpected: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsers-0.12.8/docs/Text-Parser-Combinators.html#v:unexpected ?

Answer (score 2):

Parsec:

- [`unexpected`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.13.0/docs/src/Text.Parsec.Prim.html#unexpected)
- [`fail`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.13.0/docs/src/Text.Parsec.Prim.html#parserFail)
- [`empty`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.13.0/docs/src/Text.Parsec.Prim.html#parserZero)

Trifecta:

- [`unexpected`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/trifecta-1.7.1.1/docs/src/Text-Trifecta-Parser.html#line-201)
- [`fail`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/trifecta-1.7.1.1/docs/src/Text-Trifecta-Parser.html#line-178)
- [`empty`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/trifecta-1.7.1.1/docs/src/Text-Trifecta-Parser.html#line-119)

The only difference is the error message they produce.

- Use `unexpected` on an unexpected token. `unexpected "token"` will result in an error message like `"unexpected: 'token'"`.
- Annotate parsers with the high-level constructs they represent using [`(<?>)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.13.0/docs/Text-Parsec.html#v:-60--63--62-).

  > This is normally used at the end of a set alternatives where we want to return an error message in terms of a higher level construct rather than returning all possible characters.

  ```
  parseExpr = ... <?> "expression"
  parseId = ... <?> "identifier"
  parseTy = ... <?> "type"
  ```
- `empty` doesn't produce any error message. It can still be useful to backtrack and let another branch succeed or take care of reporting a meaningful error.
- Use `fail` for other kinds of errors, libraries can't assume much about what goes into it so they'll probably treat its argument as a raw message.